# jquery datatables html string - sort column

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, datatables

I've created a table using DataTables from JQuery by inserting a string containing all the html code:

```
...
    $('#table tbody').text("<td>myrowdata</td>");
...
```

Then i apply the sorting order with the line:

```
$('#table').dataTable().fnSort([[2, 'desc']]);
```

And it all works fine, but now it's showing a lot of bonus options, like the search field, paging information etc..
And when i turn off all that features with:

```
$('table').dataTable({"bFilter": false,"bInfo": false});
```

It's stops adding information to my table.. the `$('#table').text("<td>myrowdata</td>");` is not working anymore

Comment: You should be using `.html()` to insert html code. Not `.text()`

Comment: It would be great if you could provide more details about the problem. Do you get any error message? Do you apply the `dataTable` function twice? A small example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) could be very helpful to understand the actual problem in more detail.

Comment: Did you try `$('table').DataTable({"bFilter": false,"bInfo": false});`?